# bootstrap dropdown horizontal, with images like MS office bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I want do a navbar, like the microsoft office bar.

I have this styles

```
.officeColorStyle
{
    background: #A0C0D3 !important;
    color: #A0C0D3;
}
.officeColorStyleFont
{
    background: inherit !important;
    color: #0033ff;

}
.items:hover .dropdown-menu ,dropdown-item{
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 0; 
}
.items{
   display:inline-block;
}
.dropdown-menu.officeBar
{
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 700px !important;
}
.imagesOfficeBar{
   width: 35px; height: 35px;
}
.divider-vertical {
 height: 50px;
   margin: 0 0px;
   border-left: 2px solid #F2F2F2;
   border-right: 2px solid #FFF;
   width: 100px;height: 100px;
   }
```

and this is the code in navbar

```
<div class="officeColorStyle">
        <ul>
            <div>
            <li class="dropdown items">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                        DOCUMENTOS
                    </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu officeBar officeColorStyle divider-vertical" style="position: absolute !important;">


                    <a class="dropdown-item"  href="/documentada/1">
                        <img class="imagesOfficeBar" src=" /img/navBar office style images/Politicas.jpg" />
                        <span>POLITICas</span>

                    </a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/documentada/2">
                        <i class="fa fa-book imagesOfficeBar"></i>
                        Manuales
                    </a>         
                </div>

            </li>
            </div>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

i need that the image appears on top the text, but i dont know how do this, cause the image appears before text
[image appears before text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsCIN.png)

other thing, are there any way to use bootstrap awesome fonts with pixels exact size

Thanks a lot

Comment: I want a menu like this when you hover over products
http://www.gateway.com/gw/en/US/content/home

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just add a line break?

```
<a class="dropdown-item"  href="/documentada/1">
    <span>POLITICas</span> <br />
    <img class="imagesOfficeBar" src=" /img/navBar office style images/Politicas.jpg" />
</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/99pw3njr/ - I didn't have an image in here but you can see the outline of where the image would be. Is that not what you mean?

Comment: if i do this `<a class="dropdown-item"  href="/documentada/1">
                            <img class="imagesOfficeBar" src=" /img/navBar office style images/Politicas.jpg" /><br />
                            <span>Politicas</span>
                            
                        </a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/documentada/2">
                            <i class="fa fa-book imagesOfficeBar"></i><br />
                            <span>Manuales</span>
                        </a>`
the result is [link](http://imgur.com/kG147tC)

Comment: Is that not what you wanted?